# I'm using ggplot in R version 3.5.3 trying to add to annotate text to a faceted grid but I keep getting an error about the aesthetics length

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
Tr<-c("Sorghum Male \n Sorghum Female","Sorghum Male \n Wheat Female","Wheat Male \n Sorghum Female","Wheat Male \n Wheat Female")
Treatment<-c(rep(Tr,3))
Matingdiet<-c(rep(c("Same diet","Cross diet","Cross diet", "Same diet"),3))
Rejection<-c(0.05, 0.00, 0.10, 0.00, 0.00, 0.05, 0.05, 0.00, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05)
d<-as.data.frame(cbind(Treatment,Rejection, Matingdiet))
d$pop<-c(rep("JN200A-OBL",4),rep("JN200B-OBL",4),rep("JN200C-OBL",4))
d$Rejection<-as.numeric(as.character(d$Rejection))
d$pop<-as.factor(d$pop)

datatxt<-as.data.frame(cbind(labels = rep("N = 20 per treatment",3)),pop=c("JN200A-OBL","JN200B-OBL","JN200C-OBL"))

pl<-ggplot(data = d, aes(x=Treatment, y=Rejection, fill=Matingdiet))+geom_col()+facet_wrap(~pop)
pl<-pl+labs(fill="Mating pair type", y = "Proportion of mates rejected")+ylim(0,1)+theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = -60, hjust = 1, vjust = -1))
pl<-pl+theme(plot.background = element_blank(),panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
pl+geom_text(data=datatxt,aes(label = labels))
```

Which gives this error
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (9): x, y and fill

When I run it without adding the *geom_text()* function I get my desired graph but I want to annotate it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, it looks like in your code there is a misplaced parentheses when you define `datatxt` that results in that data frame to have only one column called `labels`.  You're also using `as.data.frame()` when it makes much more sense to use simply `data.frame()`, where you do not have to use `cbind()`, but rather just list the column names as vectors, separated by `,`.

```
datatxt <- data.frame(
  labels = rep("N = 20 per treatment",3),
  pop=c("JN200A-OBL","JN200B-OBL","JN200C-OBL")
)
```

As for placing the text on your plot, if you are using `geom_text` it will be mapping the data like `ggplot` does for all the other geoms.  That is to say that what is drawn on the plot will be based on the data itself and the mapping you define in `aes()`, which is linked to the columns of that data.  For `geom_text`, it will look through each observation in the dataset you give it (in this case, `datatxt`) and look for those values pertaining to `x`, `y`, and also `fill` (because this was defined in the overall call to `ggplot()` in your plot.  The error message is due to not finding those columns in the dataset, and in fact, you do not have columns that are mapped to `x`, `y`, or `fill` in `datatxt` at all.

The first fix is to remove the `fill` aesthetic from the overall call to `ggplot()`.  If it is used in all geoms, it makes sense to put it here, but I like to define the aesthetics that are used only for particular geoms inside the geom call itself.  Hence, I'm moving `fill=Matingdiet` inside the `aes()` for `geom_col()` where it is used.  We can get around another way, but this is simplest.

Second, you presumably want the text to appear in the same location for each facet, right?  Since it's not going to move with the data, we should be defining where it goes *outside* the `mapping=` specification of `geom_text()` - in other worse, outside `aes()`.  I also change a few other aesthetics so you can see what else you may want to specify here.

Here's the result:

```
pl<-
  ggplot(data = d, aes(x=Treatment, y=Rejection)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill=Matingdiet)) +
  facet_wrap(~pop) +
  labs(fill="Mating pair type", y = "Proportion of mates rejected") +
  ylim(0,1) +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = -60, hjust = 1, vjust = -1),
    plot.background = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank()
  )

pl +
  geom_text(
    data=datatxt, aes(label = labels),
    x=1, y=0.95, hjust=0, fontface='italic', color='red')
```

[image]

Remember that `geom_text` is really supposed to be suited for the case where the value of whatever you assign inside `aes()` *changes* with respect to the data.  For example, you might have N=20 for two of the facets, but N=30 for another one.  If that's the case, you can use that approach above.  If you need to have the text remain the same regardless of the data, an easier approach might be to use `annotate()` instead:

```
pl +
  annotate(
    geom='text', x=1, y=0.95, color='red', fontface='italic',
    label='N = 20 per treatment', hjust=0
  )
```

Ultimately, it's up to you, as both work here.  The above code gives you the same plot as using `geom_text`.

Comment: I wanted to use geom_text mainly because I'd be able to modify this code for some of my other plots, which I need to annotate with different texts.
Thanks for answering this!

Comment: Sure, no problem.  The key for using `geom_text()` here is that you will want to link it to another `data=` which has only one observation per facet with the label information.  If you link it directly to the original dataset, you will get overplotting (text on top of one another) since `geom_text` will draw text on your plot for every observation in that dataset.